# How to hide Firebase credentials in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a chrome extension, and using Cloud Firestore. As mentioned in Google's documentation, I have to put the code in the JavaScript file itself, which is easily visible to anyone who can extract the source code. For security purposes, we can allow access to database only through certain domain names or certain apps. But in the case of Google Chrome extension, it is neither being hosted with a domain name nor it can be registered as an app. So, how do I not let anyone mess around with it ?

And my second question is that I have some if statements inside the chrome extension code which relates credentials from Cloud Firestore and shows result according to it. Like this -

```
if(userrefdoc.getCoins < 1){
   console.log("Not enough coins. Buy some more");
}
```

So, if someone can extract and modify my code, he can easily change the if statements according to his need and gets access to the features, which he is not allowed to use. So, how do I deal with this scenario too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to hide secrets in code JavaScript code that you ship to customers to run in their browser or device (same for Android, iOS apps).  You should assume that a determined hacker will be able to reverse engineer all the shipped code.

The Firebase init parameters are not "credentials".  They are just settings that identify your project.  There are no secrets in them.

The way to secure your data in Firebase is to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) along with [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  If you can't use Firebase Auth or security rules to to control access to your database to individual users authorized to do so, but you need public client code to read and write it, you should assume that anyone with the name of your project will be able to read and write it.

The only workaround for this involve you setting up your own backend, routing all access through it, and performing your own checks to see if the client should be able to do.